# Character count in MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sms

Is there a way of showing the character count in the MFMessageComposeViewController? I have turned it ON in the iPhone settings for the native sms app but in my app it does not show it.

Comment: I also have tried to just show to the user the visible characters he is about to send in the body. I tried with NSString lenght, but this property does not count just the visible characs, but more (control ones ...). Is there any way to get the lenght of the visible characters from a NSString?

Comment: Why are you putting control characters into the string? And don't they count to whatever length limits apply?

Comment: You are right. No need for control characters. It was this is the doc which made me suspicious of use this method:

"The number returned includes the individual characters of composed character sequences, so you cannot use this method to determine if a string will be visible when printed or how long it will appear."

Answer (score 0):

From MFMessageComposeViewController Class Reference :

> **Important**: The message composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.

It's seem that you cannot change anything to this class.

Maybe there is a way to know if the option is enabled on the iPhone and, in this case, you'll put this key in NSUserDefaults but it will be surprising.